# Is the Bluetooth 4.2 feature "Cross-Transport Key Generation/Derivation" supported by iOS 8.2?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Bluetooth 4.2 added a nifty feature, defining a way to derive Bluetooth LE pairing information from Bluetooth BR/EDR pairing information and vice versa. When an device uses both types of transport, using this new feature would avoid the need to pair each transport separately. Instead the user would just have to pair one of the two, which would automatically also pair the other one.

[iOS 8.2 added support for (parts of) Bluetooth 4.2.](http://www.bluez.org/ios-8-2-introduces-le-secure-connections-support/)

Is the BT 4.2 feature "Cross-Transport Key Generation/Derivation" supported by iOS 8.2?

Answer (score 3):

As per an Apple engineer: with iOS 8.2 not yet in a way that is usable for a 3rd party developer.

http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5784449270677504

Comment: Any update on this? Still says unresolved in openradar, but maybe they've fixed it since then and the submitter forgot to update?

Answer (score 2):

This is now available in iOS 13.  See WWDC video for more information:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901

```
cbCentralManager.connect(cbPeripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionEnableTransportBridgingKey : true])
```