# Is the Bluetooth 4.2 feature “Cross-Transport Key Generation/Derivation” supported by iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

I am developing a peripheral device operating BR/EDR and BLE. When pairing with iphone, I always need to do both pairings manually.

Does anyone know if current iOS version 10.x supports Cross Transport Key Derivation (CTKD)?

I am aware of this question what explicitly asks for iOS 8.
[Is the Bluetooth 4.2 feature "Cross-Transport Key Generation/Derivation" supported by iOS 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338592/is-the-bluetooth-4-2-feature-cross-transport-key-generation-derivation-support)

With Android this is working fine with my peripheral device. Pairing BLE also creates the BR/EDR pairing. With iOS I never saw it working.

Regards
Maz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's finally supported on iOS 13! If you're joining in Apple Developer Program, please check WWDC19 Session 901 "What's new in Core Bluetooth" for detail.